# Total commander branch view - weird behaviour?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, total-commander

I have the Total Commander 8.51 64 bit version

I have also installed ["Context menu resizer for windows"](https://imageresizer.codeplex.com/)

As you can see here  - after selecting multiple siblings images - I still can resize them:

[image]

If I `search` using Total commander (alt+f7) and then "feed to listbox" - I can do this also for **non**-siblings images :

[image]

So where is the problem ?

The problem is with CTRL+B ( branch view). which flatten all files including subfiles

If I go to  :

[image]

And then I click : CTRL+b

It doesn't show me the feature of "resize" :

[image]

**Question**

Is there any solution so that Total commander will treat ctrl+b list as a regular list like in my first 2 examples ?

Comment: I assume you have checked the settings within Total Commander for an option that would enable this behavior?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes I have checked. but I haven't found any related info

Comment: This looks like it needs to be reported to the TC developer.